# Требуется ли синхронизация get в ArrayList?

Tags: java, многопоточность, arraylist

Имеется коллекция, два потока проходятся по ней в цикле for each и распечатывают данные на консоль. Удаление или изменение элементов листа они не производят. Требуется ли синхронизация в данном случае?

Comment: Я пока использовал Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>()), возможно это избыточно.

Comment: А какие-то другие потоки делают изменения в коллекции в это время?

Comment: Нет, главный поток main заполняет коллекцию 1 раз. Затем она передается 2 другим потокам, которые проходятся по ней и вызывают методы у объектов в коллекции получает данные и печатает на консоль. Состояние объектов не изменяется. В коллекцию больше ничего не добавляется и не удаляется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, не требуется. Если не происходит изменение, синхронизация не требуется, вообще. Удаление относится к изменению. Это правило для всех коллекций действительно